# Fixed area for footnotes: is it possible?

Tags: footnotes, height

Is it possible to dedicate to footnotes a same fixed (possibly empty) area, with same height, on each page? Of course, in case of too long footnote text, it should continue on the next page (area) as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Main problem is the "possibly empty" bit.

Try

```
\setlength{\dimen\footins}{2\in} % or whatever
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\dimen\footins}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0pt}
\global\count\footins=0\relax
```

This is almost what you want, but the footnote rule will have to be changed to take up the space previously occupied by `\skip\footins`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you expand this answer to show this working in an actual document.  This often a useful supplement to code snippets.

Comment: This leads to very weak pages.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a complete MWE (minimum working example), starting with `\documentclass` and ending in `\end{document}` to demonstrate your proposed fix.